# In my python code i get the error 'await' outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

Whenever i try to make a Chatbot
I choose to use endpoint

**But i get this error
File "/app/chatbot/plugins/response.py", line 10
print((await get_response('world')))
^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function**

*Please help me i would be highly obliged if you help me*

Where my code is

```
import aiohttp

async def get_response(query):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
        async with ses.get(
            f'https://some-random-api.ml/chatbot?message={query}'
        ) as resp:
            return (await resp.json())['response']

print((await get_response('world')))
```

Comment: The last line uses `await` *outside* of the `async` function. You're not allowed to do that.

Comment: How would i solve it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution:

`await` is used in an `async` functions/methods to wait on other asynchronous tasks, but if you are calling an `async` function/method outside of an `async` function/method you need to use `asyncio.run()` method to call an async function/method

**Here is the full solution:**

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio #to run async funtions you need to import asyncio

async def get_response(query):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
        async with ses.get(
            f'https://some-random-api.ml/chatbot?message={query}'
        ) as resp:
            return (await resp.json())['response']

print((asyncio.run( get_response('world')))#run the async function
```